# Unusual notation of passing by reference?

Tags: php

In a legacy php script I found the following line of code:

```
$CacheLite =& ( "string" );
```

Which provokes an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   '(', expecting T_NEW or T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE or '$'

Is it a mistake or a way of passing by reference or something else I don't know. Do I have to enable/disable something in my php configuration in order for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign by reference to a literal value, or to an expression, in PHP; it has to be a reference to a variable. I have no idea how that line of code got there (why is `$CacheLite` being assigned to some random string anyway?) — probably a mistake in the legacy code.

Comment: I took the & off as a pragmatic solution... and I'm paying for this piece of ****. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Assignment by reference exists, but only *variables* can be passed/assigned as references. Values (integers, strings, etc.) and expressions (like `("string")`) can't.

This is how you assign by reference:

```
$a = "string";
$b = &$a;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no clue what they were trying to do, I just deleted the &.

Answer (score 1):

That must be a mistake. There is no such syntax. Creating a reference to a literal or expression is just bogus.